# Trying to loop through the elements using Beautifulsoup But I keep getting 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I keep getting the error

```
'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'a'
```

If I try it like this

```
        def get_vlad(url):
            html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
            divs = soup.findAll('section', 'videos')[0]

            entries = [{'text': div.strong.a.text,
                        'link': div.a.get('href'),
                        'img': div.find('img').get('src')
                        } for div in divs]
            return entries
```

I get this error

```
 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'a'
```

but if I do it like this

```
        def get_vlad(url):
            html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
            divs = soup.findAll('section', 'videos')

            entries = [{'text': div.strong.a.text,
                        'link': div.a.get('href'),
                        'img': div.find('img').get('src')
                        } for div in divs]
            return entries
```

It works. But there are about 4

```
<div class="video">
```

divs. So it takes the first video from each

```
<div class="video">
```

section. But I want to iterate through all the videos in the same div. So I did this

```
divs = soup.findAll('section', 'videos')[0]
```

but that give me the error so I tried this

```
divs = soup.find('section', 'videos')
```

Thinking that it would target the first video div and loop through all of those divs but that didn't work heres the html structure I'm scraping

```
        <section class="video">
            <section class="box">
                    <a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b" class="video-box">
                    <img src="http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/2cuPh1LdFzJo.jpg" width="222" height="125" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b">Stays Wildin: Blac Youngsta Showing Out With His Money!</a></strong>
                    <div>
                    <span class="views">318,105</span> 
                    <span class="comments"><a href="http://www.example.org/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="94122">3717</a></span>
                    </div>
            </section>

            <section class="box">
                    <a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b" class="video-box">
                    <img src="http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/2cuPh1LdFzJo.jpg" width="222" height="125" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b">Stays Wildin: Blac Youngsta Showing Out With His Money!</a></strong>
                    <div>
                    <span class="views">318,105</span> 
                    <span class="comments"><a href="http://www.example.org/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="94122">3717</a></span>
                    </div>
            </section>

            <section class="box">
                    <a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b" class="video-box">
                    <img src="http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/2cuPh1LdFzJo.jpg" width="222" height="125" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b">Stays Wildin: Blac Youngsta Showing Out With His Money!</a></strong>
                    <div>
                    <span class="views">318,105</span> 
                    <span class="comments"><a href="http://www.example.org/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="94122">3717</a></span>
                    </div>
            </section>
    </section>

    <section class="video"></section>
    <section class="video"></section>
```

I want to iterate through the first

```
<section class="video">
```

and pull all the videos out from there. What's currently happening with my code is I'm pulling the first video from each video section which is not what I want to do. So why won't this

```
divs = soup.findAll('section', 'videos')[0]
```

or this

```
divs = soup.find('section', 'videos')
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming all the sections actually contain elements this will work, you need to use `div.find("strong")` and the class is *video* not *videos*:

```
divs = soup.find_all('section', 'video')
entries = [{'text': div.find("strong").a.text,
            'link': div.a.get('href'),
            'img': div.find('img').get('src')
            } for div in divs]
```

If there are actually some tags like `<section class="video"></section>` or not all the children are in each then you are going to have to take that into account and filter those. also `divs = soup.findAll('section', 'video')[0]` would get the first *video section* which is the same as using find, if you want them all then you need to use find_all and just iterate as you are.

The data you want to get also seems to be on the *class=box* which is actually what you seem to want:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"html5lib")


sections= soup.select("section.video section.box")
print(sections)

entries = [{'text': sec.find("strong").a.text,
            'link': sec.a.get('href'),
            'img': sec.find('img').get('src')
            } for sec in sections]


from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(entries)
```

which gives you:

```
[{'img': u'http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/2cuPh1LdFzJo.jpg',
  'link': u'/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b',
  'text': u'Stays Wildin: Blac Youngsta Showing Out With His Money!'},
 {'img': u'http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/2cuPh1LdFzJo.jpg',
  'link': u'/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b',
  'text': u'Stays Wildin: Blac Youngsta Showing Out With His Money!'},
 {'img': u'http://hw-static.example.org/u/pic/2016/05/2cuPh1LdFzJo.jpg',
  'link': u'/videos/video.php?v=wshhO9CO5349voIH6k6b',
  'text': u'Stays Wildin: Blac Youngsta Showing Out With His Money!'}]
```

Obviously they are all the same using the sample but I presume in the real html they are all different, if you want to break the data up into each video section, first get the video sections then look for the `section.box` in each.

Comment: thanks for the reply I'm going to try that right now. and the class is videos, a copy and pasting error

Comment: @nothingness, try the edit first and see if that is what you actually want

Comment: it does not work. And is this syntax correct in your code ("section.video section.box") I've never seen that in all the examples that I've seen

Comment: It works using your sample exactly as you see it in my answer, `("section.video section.box")` is a css selector and perfectly valid, if you shared the link it might help

Comment: I didn't make myself clear when I said it does not work. The text part of your two part answer works. but the looping through the video section does not work. I'm going to go over my code again. thanks for the text part though. i really needed that part.

Comment: I could be wrong But I feel like since I changed from videos to box that the syntax I'm looping over should be rearranged becausewhen I try what you suggest I get the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: The only way that happens is if not all the tags have the children you are looking for, there is no silver bullet for that,  you can use explicit loop with a try/except to catch missing data.

Comment: I partly figured it out. It's the dot syntax that i questioned you about. i'm using django so in my template soup.findAll('section', 'videos') this works but this soup.findAll('section.videos') returns all unformated code

Comment: Where am I using `soup.findAll('section.videos') `?

Comment: soup.select("section.video section.box") this probably works fine in terminal but not in django it returns all unformatted codeI'm thinking I may have to go one element up/backwards a level to scrape what I want

Comment: You should not be using that at all, that gets the sections, you then pull the data from each  sections in entries. I don't output anything directly from sections anywhere in my code

Comment: but isn't that what you have in your code above? that's what you suggested? If i misunderstood could you shed some light? and give me some clarity. and So I'm clear what should I not be using? this soup.select("section.video section.box")

Comment: Put the code in a function, `return entries` and it follows exactly the same logic pattern as your own code. Why would you output sections when you have used entries in your own code?